# Best OpenCV version for ROS Noetic

Tags: ros, opencv, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran this command to find out if my OpenCV version was 4:

```
kg-config --modversion opencv4
```

The outcome was:

```
4.2.0
```

I also tried importing it after calling python3 on the lxterminal, verifying that the version I'm using is 4.

My ROS distro is Noetic, would that version of OpenCV work here? Should I install OpenCV2? If the answer is affirmative, would that cause any conflict of interest with OpenCV4?

Thanks in advance for any input.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362202/best-opencv-version-for-ros-noetic./) by [ajpaezm](https://answers.ros.org/users/56993/ajpaezm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-09-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on 2020-09-24**:
i could guess between opencv3 and opencv4, but opencv2 i think is so old, isn't?

from http://wiki.ros.org/vision_opencv
Seems like the standard is opencv3 (at the end it says that). In melodic i had issues with 4.2 but nevertheless is possible to work with 4.2 if you search through internet, and personally seems to be much better in performance the 4.2, so, up to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> My ROS distro is Noetic, would that version of OpenCV work here?

There is only a one version for which Noetic binary packages are built on Ubuntu Focal (`20.04`): that would be version `4.2`.

Refer to [REP 3 - Target Platforms: Noetic Ninjemys (May 2020 - May 2025)](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#noetic-ninjemys-may-2020-may-2025) for information on which specific versions of the various dependencies are supported.

Technically `vision_opencv` should support the range of versions listed in the row for OpenCV (so `3.2` and `4.2`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ajpaezm](https://answers.ros.org/users/56993/ajpaezm/) on 2020-09-24**:
Got it, thanks a lot.

**Comment by [ajpaezm](https://answers.ros.org/users/56993/ajpaezm/) on 2020-09-24**:
Something else @gvdhoorn:

In my CMakeLists.txt file, I have the following line:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
```

Should I change that in order to point out the proper OpencV version?